# Why is a retain cycle being caused?

Tags: ios, swift, eureka-forms

I am using [Eureka](https://github.com/xmartlabs/Eureka) to set up my table view. I have a section with a header:

```
Section() { [weak self] in
    guard let strongSelf = self else { return }
    var header = HeaderFooterView<MyView>(.nibFile(name: "MView", bundle: nil))
    header.onSetupView = strongSelf.setUpHeader(view:section:)
    $0.header = header
    ...
}

private func setUpHeader(view: MyView, section: Section) {
    // content here doesn't seem to make a difference.
}
```

For some reason it always sets up a retain cycle on the line `header.onSetupView = strongSelf.setUpHeader(view:section:)`. If I move the code from the `setUpHeader(view: MyView, section: Section)` function into a block like this, there is no retain cycle:

```
header.onSetupView = { [weak self] view, section in

}
```

Why is this??

Comment: Have you tried strongSelf.header = header instead $0.header = header?

Comment: @Vanya the $0 belongs to the section rather than self

Comment: `self` retains the `section` but `section` retains `self` implicitly since it retains the header of self..

Comment: @Brandon  I think I kind of get what you mean, but could you expand on it a bit in an answer?

Comment: what are the arguments you pass in setUpHeader(view:section:). maybe they are strong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
header.onSetupView = strongSelf.setUpHeader(view:section:)
```

This line creates a strong reference to `strongSelf`, which is a strong reference to `self`, so transitively that creates a strong reference to `self` in the `onSetupView` closure.

Saying it another way, what you've written here is the same as:

```
header.onSetupView = { view, section in
    strongSelf.setupHeader(view: view, section: section)
}
```

And since `strongSelf` is a strong reference to `self`, that's the same thing as strong reference to `self`:

```
header.onSetupView = { view, section in
    self.setupHeader(view: view, section: section)
}
```

And just one more way to say it: `self` cannot be deallocated before `strongSelf` is, because then `strongSelf` would be an invalid reference.

Comment: Additional words: Swift functions and closures are known as "First-Class" functions.. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First-class_function and assigning them to anything creates a strong reference to the owner of the function. :)